# Line break problem - parsing string into blob, ContentNote object

Tags: apex

In a record I create a new Note (ContentNote object) with the text contained into a custom field. 
So for that I have to parse the text area of the custom field (string) into a blob (the type of the Content field of the ContentNote object).

Here is what I've done (simplified):

```
    ContentNote cn = new ContentNote();
    String body = customeField__c;
    cn.Content = Blob.valueOf(body.escapeHTML4());
    insert cn;
```

So this code works fine, I add the `escapeHTML4()` because I need the escape the characters. 
My problem is that the line break are not re-rendered in the ContentNote, when I put a line break in the text area, in the ContentNote I got nothing, and event no space between words.

How can I display the line break into the blob ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, thanks for a nice question.

I have checked that, Content Note puts line break into `<p></p>` instead of `<br/>`.

For the sake of experiment, I have created a Case description like this.

[image: case description]

> **Execute from Developer Console**

```
String strdesc = [SELECT Id, Description From Case WHERE Id = '50090000001N25E' LIMIT 1].Description ;
String returnStr = strdesc;
if (strdesc.contains('\n'))
{
    returnStr = '<p>' + strdesc.replaceAll('\n','</p><p>') + '</p>';
}
System.debug('strdesc=' + returnStr);
ContentNote cn = new ContentNote();
cn.title = 'test16';
String body = returnStr;
cn.Content = Blob.valueOf(body);
insert cn;
System.debug('createdRecord=' + cn.id);
```

> **Debug Log**

[image: Debug log]

> **Content Note**

[image: Content Note]

> Following things to be noted:

1. To create line break, find `\n` characters and replace  with `<\p><p>`.
2. You need to put extra `<p>` to both start and end position of the string.
3. **DO NOT use escapeHTML3() or  escapeHTML4(), as it is already formatted as HTML, so it does not need to be escaped.**

You can prepare a reusable method for this:

```
public String prepareContent(String input)
{
    String returnStr = input;
    if (input.contains('\n'))
    {
        returnStr = '<p>' + input.replaceAll('\n','</p><p>') + '</p>';
    }
    return returnStr;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the very complete answer! Is there a risk using ` escapeHTML4()` ?

Comment: Points 1 and 2 are a good solution, however `escapeHTML4()` MUST be used (prior to step 1 and 2). Emojis (e.g. `<3`) will break everything coming after if they are not escaped